# Pentaho BI - MongoDB input Aggregation error due to recent MongoDB upgrade to 3.6

Tags: aggregation-framework, pentaho, kettle, karaf, pentaho-data-integration

Due to recent Mogodb upgrade to 3.6, pentaho kettle mongoinput step aggregation not be able to fetch data from the Mongodb.

The error message:

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The
>   'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain
>   argument' on server localhost:2915. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0,
>   "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with
>   the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }

It seems that I need to upgrade mongodb driver for the pentaho, so I've downloaded mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar file and saved it inside pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\karaf\system\org\mongodb\mongo-java-driver\3.6.3, but the issue still exists.

I don't really know what to do to upgrade the driver and whether there is additional configuration associated with it or not.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a new version, you need to:

1. download new version (for example https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.1/mongo-java-driver-3.7.1.jar) to directory system/karaf/system/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.1 (where 3.7.1 is version of mongo driver - 3.7.1 works fine with mongo 3.6 too)
2. point in configuration (system/karaf/system/pentaho/pentaho-karaf-features/7.0.0.0-25/pentaho-karaf-features-7.0.0.0-25-standard.xml) a new version of module mongo-java-driver
3. remove cache (system/karaf/caches/) to allow rebuild it.