# Adding condition on a date field in PDI

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am using PDI to extract data from the database. I am having a problem where i cannot add a condition in date field as it always gives error.

I have tried following ways

```
{news_date: {$gte: ISODate("2020-12-30")} }
{news_date: {$gte: new Date("2020-12-30")} }
```

nothing is working and I am always getting errors. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. How do I pull data from mongo DB filtered on Date?

following is the error i am getting on preview which also makes no sense to me
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to specify the aggregation stage ( in this case this is $match stage )

Comment: @kiko i did still same issue.

Comment: Maybe remove the square brackets in the above window so it accept the stage correctly

Comment: @kiko075 Tried that, same issue. Also all other queries are working correctly with square brackets. i am using projection, match, addfield in other transformation and everything works. as soon as i add a check on date i start getting errors that make no sence. if you see the screenshots i attached the error is on a line which is not in the query....

Comment: It seems this is specific to PDI , can you try: { "news_date" : { $gte : { $date : "2020-12-30T00:00:00Z" }}}

Comment: Also check the pdi mongo java driver need to be up compatible with the database , see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039298/pentaho-bi-mongodb-input-aggregation-error-due-to-recent-mongodb-upgrade-to-3

Comment: @kiko075 This works thanks a lot, One last question if you can help. how to i specify a variable instead of hardcoded date like  { "news_date" : { $gte : { $date : ${DATE} }}} or  { "news_date" : { $gte : { $date : "${DATE}" }}}

Comment: In the native mongodb JavaScript shell you can define variables  before the aggregation like in JS as follow: var x = "The value"  and you can use it later in the aggregation , example:  var x = "2020-12-30"; db.aggregate([  {$match:{ y:x }}  ])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226553/discussion-between-ghengalala-and-kiko075).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
{ news_date: { $gte: ISODate("2020-12-30T00:00:00.000Z")} }
```

But how the stored news_date looks like?

Comment: Not working for me. i have added the query and message screenshot with the question as well

Comment: example of a stored date is 2021-12-29T08:59:43.000+00:00